# BeautifulSoup, what order does .descendants go in?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When using the beautifulsoup [soup.descendants](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#descendants) iterator, are the tags yielded guaranteed to come back in any particular order? Since the documentation mentions that things are iterated over recursively, I'd guess that things are returned in DFS order, but I'm not sure if this is something I can rely on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#descendants) does not promise anything, but [the source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/element.py#L1269) reveals all. `.descendants` yields tags in [`.next_element`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-element-and-previous-element) order:

> The .next_element attribute of a string or tag points to whatever was parsed immediately afterwards. It might be the same as .next_sibling, but it’s usually drastically different.